# jquery show/hide doesn't wait for completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I am trying to periodically:

1. Fetch data from an ajax call
2. compare the data to the content of a div
3. if data != content of the div: hide the div, change data, show the div

Here is my code:

```
...

<div id="myDiv">old data</div>   
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
    updates();
    done();
});

function done() {
      setTimeout( function() {
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 5000);
}

function replace(div, content){
    $(div).html(content)
}

function updates() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON("mywebsite/get_data", function(data) {
        if ( $("#myDiv").html() !== data ){
            $("#myDiv").hide(400, replace("#myDiv", data));
            $("#myDiv").show(400);
        }
    });
}

</script>

...
```

The problem is that div content is replaced by the new data **before** the div is completely hidden, even if the callback function replace() is supplied to the hide() function.

How can make the hide() function to wait for its completion (400 ms in this example) before calling the replace() function?

I also tried with delay() and setTimeout() but it does the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the code, I'd be surprised if the `div` is hidden at all.  The call to `show()` should also be in the callback for `hide()` or it will execute immediately.

Comment: You don't have to use `;` to end your JS line but you should. Especially if you ask people to look at your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need that `replace` function. Anyway this should work:

```
function updates() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON("mywebsite/get_data", function(data) {
        if ( $("#myDiv").html() !== data ) {
            $("#myDiv").hide(400, function() {
                $("#myDiv").html(data);
                $("#myDiv").show(400);
            })
        }
    });
}
```

[**SEE JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qEExn/) (without ajax call)